# @font-face doesn't work even though the source is correct

Tags: css, import, font-face

I am just trying to import and make use of a font I generated on http://www.fontsquirrel.com

This is my css for embedding the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'robotothin';
    src: url('../fonts/webfont/roboto-thin-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/webfont/roboto-thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/webfont/roboto-thin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/webfont/roboto-thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/webfont/roboto-thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/webfont/roboto-thin-webfont.svg#robotothin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

and this is how I try to make use of it.

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'robotothin';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and this is where I stor my fonts

[image]

Just don't know why it won't work. Please help me!

Comment: Do you see any messages in your browser’s console when you try to load the page? For example, is it getting an HTTP 404 when it tries to download the font?

Comment: nah, I already checked console erros, but nothing!

Comment: Do you serve your fonts by a webserver? Is one of the roboto-*-demo.html working?

Comment: @slime I have to go one folder up becuase my css is laying in another folder next to the fonts folder.

Comment: @gearsdigital I am working locally using xampp

Comment: I don't see a roboto-th.... font in your list, are you sure they are there?

Comment: @Devin nice try:D look at the scroll bar, yes they are there. I already checked that multiple times before I started posting my issue

Comment: I'm just trying to find a reason to something that shouldn't happen at all, the only options I can think of is wrong paths or wrong file names. If both of them are correct, then you have something really strangely weird going on and I have no idea what could it be since there's no logical explanation

Comment: @Devin true that! But it doesn't have anything to do with me using xampp, right?

Comment: no that I know of, but I don't use XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

Use the google fonts version of that font http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto
add this to your html

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,900italic,900,400italic,100,700italic,300,700,500italic,100italic,300italic,400&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And this to where you want to use the font

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9rcs073/) of it in action

Comment: thanks for the hint. I didnt even know this one was available on google. Anyway, its kinda strange, why it doesn't work with my local fonts...

Comment: No problem. I hope my solution was of help to you?

Comment: well its actually not a solution to my problem, but a good alternative, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad, feel free to accept my answer if you found it helpful. Or drop a comment if you need any further help. Also about your problem i do believe that the issue is in the server since the CSS has no visible problem in it

Comment: it was helpful thats why I upvoted, but its not the solution to my problem